# Cannot use array_search() when entity has Apostrophes in them

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, htmlspecialchars

I'm having an issue where I have a list of company's as an array and I am using `array_search()` to get the Keys from this array to store in a database as an ID.

This works with all of my company's except ones with apostrophes in them!
I don't know how `array_search()` works specifically but I can't find a solution posted online for this.

```
<?php
$array = array("pipefix", "Housing ltd","o'briens roofing","argos");
$search = "o'briens roofing";

$id = array_search($search, $array);
print_r($id);
```

This is obviosuly not my exact code, but is the same principle, I am trying to search the array for my company, but if it has an `'` in it, it will always return nothing! Any ideas or solutions for this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping them using `\\`

Comment: `array_search` doesn't treat any characters specially.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you have different characters in the search string and the array, like maybe one of them is a smart quote, not a regular ASCII apostrophe.

Comment: The code you posted works fine: http://ideone.com/wmudYk

Comment: I just tried creating a fresh input for it like i have done in this code. it didn't work either, i think it could be as barmar suggest a smart quote but how do i get around that seeing as i am pulling the array from an API?

Comment: I just printed the array, and copied the value into my code and set it as a variable to search with and still nothing, i don't understand if array_search() does not handle it in the wrong way as checking the input before it goes in to the array, it is identical!

Comment: until a fix is found im going to avoid the issue by changing where i pull the array in to remove all apostrophe's :) thanks for the help attempts though sorry i cant show more :(

Comment: can you post a sample of the array that doesn't work to somewhere I can access it.? or use `bin2hex` on one of the offending array entries. That way you can see what the actual character is.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent An array value that fails is    

`      [193] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 65
            [Name] => Steve&apos;s Flat
        )
`
    This is pulled from an API using Curl and then converted using JSON. This creats an array object which i convert into an array, making each [ID] the Key and the Customer name the value using this code.   

 `      foreach($customers as $customer){ $nicearray[customer['ID']] = strtolower(htmlspecialchars_decode($customer['Name']));
}`

Comment: after trying to remove the apostrophe's i noticed i couldnt do it after the `htmlspecchar_decode` so i have done it as `$apos;s` before it gets decoded.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent The company names are not stored in the database, only the ID's for management. that is why i use the `array_search()`. it just so on the back end it swaps the users selection from my search menu to translate into a value the database can handle. The cUrl may be the issue but i cannot remove it as it is required fr pulling the data from our billings database. it is displayed on a custom API that is escaped then before i get to handle it. so i feel like the best solution is the remove `&apos;s`. Thanks for the help though, at least i now know why! !!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That makes a lot of sense as to what is happening and why you ended up with the ''replace'.  May I suggest that you add that information to your question or post it as an answer as it explains clearly what is happening..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array i used is pulled from another databases stored information and is posted on an API that i have no control over unfortunately.

I do not store this my my database, I only store the [ID's] for management and inputs.

The array pulled is HTML encoded when retrieved.

I pulled this array from the API using `JSON` and `cUrl`. This means when i first get hold of the array values the `Apostrophe` has been converted to  `&apos;s`.

I thought using `htmlsecialchars_decode()` would revert this.  Thanks to Ryan Vincent he has shown me the issue is created when it is Pulled using `cUrl`.

Unfortunately i can not change this so when the array is created, I now do a `str_replace()` and simply remove the `&apos;s`.

This means once displayed it is technically incorrect. but as this is only being used by a few people it is more efficient to do this than have to do it on the back end for every search.